# django orm not interacting with database (the title name is not showing up in queryset)

Tags: django

I'm entirely new to programming and i'm not all that good with every computer science term, anyway,inside this `Django` tutorial i'm learning to create a blog site. Right now, we are at the point where we are using the `Django` ORM to interact with the database. I was following every step and i hit a wall at queryset, where the item name isn't showing up, and this was after i

```
def __str__(self):
return self.title
```

the output that i get when i type

```
 Narticle.objects.all() is 
queryset Narticle:Narticle object(1) instead of 
<queryset [<Narticle: 'hello world']>
```

my model for narticle is

```
from django.db import models


class Narticle(models.Model):
  title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug= models.SlugField()
  body= models.TextField(max_length= 100)
  date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
```

i entered the following on the command line:

```
from narticle.model import Narticle
```

i typed Narticle and i got

```
<class 'narticle.models.Narticle' >
```

i then entered the following

```
Narticle.objects.all()
```

and i got

```
<queryset[]>
```

i then typed

```
narticle= Narticle()
```

then

```
narticle
```

which gave me

```
Narticle: Narticle object(none)
```

i then typed

```
narticle.title = "hello world"
```

which was followed by

```
Narticle.objects.all()
```

Which gave me

```
< queryset [<Narticle: Nartice object (1)>]>
```

i typed 
    narticle.save()

i then exited command line,and then in models.py of narticle i typed

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.title
```

i then went back to command line and repeated the process of importing Narticle

Then i typed 
    Narticle.objects.all()

which gave me

```
< queryset [<Narticle: Nartice object (1)>]>
```

instead of

```
 <queryset [<Narticle: 'hello world']>
```

oh and why is it that the word "none", and then (1), when i make an entry'like this

```
<Narticle: Narticle object (none)>
```

or in case of an entry

```
<Narticle: Narticle object (1)>
```

instead of

```
 <Narticle: Narticle object>
```

the programme wasnt running before and it worked when i used migrate...just in case you would want to know...
thanks again for taking the time out to look at my code

Comment: Could you please share the whole model (Narticle)? 

It prints queryset Model:Model object (1) when str representation doesn't exists.

Comment: thanks for the consideration, i placed in there all that i did, thanks again for taking the time out to help me

Comment: Where did you put the `__str__' method?

Comment: you are override the save method ?

Comment: i placed the __str__ method in models.py of narticle xbello

Comment: i dont understand the question roberto... oh and thanks for replying guys :)!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function that tells the class which attribute(s) to use when printing out the object. This is sometimes called a toString function because it tells the computer how to convert an object which can have many parts into a single string. In python, there are two built-in toString methods that can be overwritten in any class to define how to print an object: __repr__ and __str__. The difference isn't important for your question. The simple answer is to add one of them to the class definition like the following.

```
from django.db import models


class Narticle(models.Model):
  title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug= models.SlugField()
  body= models.TextField(max_length= 100)
  date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```